# NMOS inverter with enchancement load behaving weirdly in LTspice

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

[image]

The green line is the output voltage and the red line is the ferivative of the output voltage.

[image]

I was simulating this circuit and the derivative shows horrible fluctuations. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: @V.V.T My understanding is broken, the problem is I don't understand why exactly is the MOSFET conducting when the output should be at 2V until Vgs=0.9 which is the threshold voltage. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @V.V.T, From the diagram the Enchancement Load MOSFEt would be in saturation, hence it will behave like a non linear reaistor with varying output voltage. I am have no idea why the values are fluctuting that much though because with an Enchancement MOSFET there should be a sharp transition as VIL=Vth.

Comment: @V.V.T by conducting I meant that the driver MOSFET seems to turn on before crossing Vth in the input (x-axis of the graph)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116316/discussion-between-redlion11-and-v-v-t).

Comment: @V.V.T yes. miniscule amount of current should flow.

Comment: @V.V.T I am not asking for a full solution, I would be glad if you could guide me to the solution, I have been at it for half a day and I am still struck.

Comment: @V.V.T according to the datasheet the max Zero gate voltage drain current is 100uA, at 125 °C. So assuming that the Drain current is 5 times lower at room temperature, I get 25uA+100nA (100nA is the Gate body leakage) while resistance is very high there should be a siginifcant voltage drop across the mosfet hence resulting in a small voltage passing through the drain to the source. Small value could be so small as to cause errors in calculation errors in the simulator? If I am understanding that correctly.

Comment: One issue I see is that the type of circuit you're trying to simulate is meant for IC MOSFETs and not discrete vertical diffused ones (VDMOS).  You need to use the `nmos4` symbols and connect the 4th terminal (body) to GND, as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxZez.png

Comment: @SteKulov, may I ask what is the difference between those types? and how that would effect my circuit?

Comment: MOSFETs are 4-terminal devices and are really operated with respect to the body node.  In ICs, the body of NMOS is always connected to VSS while the PMOS are connected to VDD.  In discrete FETs, source and body are inherently connected together via how "VDMOS" topology is constructed.  See here for more info:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vlsi_design/vlsi_design_mos_inverter.htm

Comment: @SteKulov Ahh, I see thanks!!!

Comment: If you need to implement 4-terminal MOSFET circuits in real-life, ALD (advanced linear devices) is the only company I know which provides these.  Example:  http://aldinc.com/pdf/ALD1116.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a basic `.dc` simulation, which gives a finite amount of points, here `200` (from `0` to `2`, in `0.01` steps). The waveform arithmetic derivative, `d()`, operates directly on the saved `.raw` data, data that is saved as soon as the buffer is filled, as the simulation is going. If you are performing the derivative, you are doing it for a unity value, which means any differences you may have at higher than `10...100` times the frequency, will be exaggerated.

In `.tran`, this can be alleviated by using `.opt plotwinsize=0`, which disables waveform compression. In `.dc`, your only bet is to use more points. Since a `.dc` is WYSIWYG as far as the number of simulation points go, you can increase them to your heart desire, but the simulation will go slower.

If you can tolerate it, use `.tran` (with `.opt plotwinsize=0`) involving a ramp at the input (e.g. make `V2` to be `pwl 0 0 1 2`, or `2 V/s`). You can then use whatever timestep suits you and disable compression, which will give you more accurate displays of `d()`.

However, if you'll be using `.tran`, I'd recommend not using `d()` for the derivative, instead use a VCCS and an inductor for that:

[image: .tran]

I used `.tran` and the display of `d()` and the derivative performed with `G1+L1` are quite the same, and not noisy. This is also because the default number of points for `.tran` is `1024`. Note that I haven't used `plotwinsize`, but that would only increase the resolution (at the cost of a larger `.raw` file).

Answer (score 1):

EDA simulators are extraordinarily accurate when used for modeling ubiquitous designs. No wonder, the software developers test their programs for use cases embracing numerous typical designs.

The OP investigates the behavior of two stacked enhanced NMOS's; as the bottom transistor is cutoff, the source electrode of the top transistor is relentlessly seeking its right voltage because of the condition imposed by the transistor's shorted gate and drain electrodes. The circuitry in this voltage range is anything but the conventional design; yet, it is very instructive to examine the simulator behavior outside the typical use cases.

A transistor in cutoff mode poses a problem for the simulator computing the voltages and currents; to understand why, it is very useful to carry out the modified nodal analysis by hand. The standard method is to use the current shunt with very big resistance in parallel with a zero-conducting component.

If we add these shunts to the OP's circuit, the "fluctuations" at low voltage disappear:

[image]

In practice, the simulator itself, within its code, carries out this procedure when dealing with circuits that include ideal current sources, FETs, and diodes. The shunt value is controlled by the Gmin parameter, which we can directly assign in netlists. In LTspice, the default value of this parameter is 1E-12:

[image]

and the OP's simulation:

[image]

Benefiting from this feature, we eliminate "fluctuations" without disturbing our design:

[image]
[image]

If we resolutely decide to turn to "tempering of evidence", the increasing of Gmin is our only complicit. Decreasing the sweep parameter step's value won't help. The simulation with a .001 voltage step deteriorates the graph raggedness:

[image]

But we should use the Gmin adjustment technique with great care: this method not only smooths curves, it also distorts the results in a systematic way. See, for example, the simulation results with Gmin=1E-14, the value being supposedly closer to "real life" infinite resistance:

[image]
[image]

The graph data at greater sweep voltages are different than the graph with Gmin=1E-12, although this is masked by greater "fluctuations" and additional processing is required to notice the pronounced changes.

To better understand what happens during a simulation, I recommend you to examine the error log which sometimes pops up at the end of simulation (see a manual how to access this log if it does not pop up):

```
    Circuit: * C:\...\LTspiceXVII\Draft1.asc
    
    Error on line 1073 : .model tn0702 nmos(level=3 rs=3.56e-3 nsub=1.0e15 delta=0.1 kappa=0.10123 tpg=1 cgdo=8.3432e-10 rf=0.2039 vto=0.900 vmax=1.0e7 eta=0.0223089 nfs=6.6e10 tox=7e-8 ld=1.698e-9 uo=862.425 xj=6.4666e-7 theta=1.0e-5 cgso=5.21798e-9 l=2.5e-6 w=2.0e-2)
        * Unrecognized parameter "rf" -- ignored
    Direct Newton iteration failed to find .op point.  (Use ".option noopiter" to skip.)
    Starting Gmin stepping
    Gmin = 10
    Gmin = 1.07374
    ...
    Gmin = 3.12175e-015
    Gmin = 0
    Gmin stepping succeeded in finding the operating point.
    
    Direct Newton iteration failed to find .op point.  (Use ".option noopiter" to skip.)
    Starting Gmin stepping
    Gmin = 10
    Gmin = 1.07374
    ...
    Gmin = 2.90735e-014
    vernier = 0.5
    Gmin = 7.43443e-015
    vernier = 0.666667
    vernier = 0.888888
    Gmin = 1.43537e-015
    Gmin = 0
    Gmin stepping succeeded in finding the operating point.
    
    Direct Newton iteration failed to find .op point.  (Use ".option noopiter" to skip.)
    Starting Gmin stepping
    Gmin = 10
    Gmin = 1.07374
    ...
    vernier = 0.000578703
    Gmin = 1.14654e-014
    vernier = 0.000771604
    vernier = 0.000578703
    vernier = 0.000434027
    Gmin = 0
    Gmin stepping succeeded in finding the operating point.

etc.
```

You perform the simulation because you need to compute your models and not in the pursuit of smooth graphs. For that same reason, substituting transient analysis results for volt ampere characteristics, however tricky it may seem, is not the option, too.

To better understand the subtleties of the simulator operation and how to use these in design and production with maximum effect and minimum effort, the engineers need to learn calculus and numerical methods.

The differential algebraic equations which the simulators solve are **stiff**, and it is the root of the difficulties in this particular case of "fluctuating voltage derivative".

Comment: `d()` is known to be noisy because it relies on the data saved on the disk. If there is waveform compression applied, the results will be that much noisier. In `.dc` it's a different animal. As you've seen, and explained in my answer, the smaller the step, the higher the noise, because it differentiates a raw discrete sequence, while in `.tran` a polynomial smoothing is applied. `Gmin` should only be a solution in case of emergencies, as it affects the whole circuit (every node to ground). Using `Gmin` to fix the noisy `d()` in `.dc` is not a recommended method.