# plot the max slopes of Voltage-Transfer characteristics in ngspice

Tags: simulation, cmos, spice, ngspice

I have implemented a basic CMOS inverter in ngspice, performing a DC sweep analysis on the input voltage to obtain the Voltage Transfer Curves (Vout vs Vin) at varying Vdd voltages.

```
. cmos g (gain) vs vdd

.include tsmc180.txt

vdd source_p 0 0v
vin gate_common 0 0v

m_p out gate_common source_p source_p cmosp w=2u l=0.18u
m_n out gate_common 0 0 cmosn w=2u l=0.18u

.dc vin 0 2.5 0.01 vdd 0.5 2.5 0.5
.control
run
plot v(out) vs v(gate_common) 
plot deriv(v(out)) vs v(gate_common)
.endc
.end
```

On running the above, it gives me two plots as expected, one the VTC and another the slopes of the vtc which represent the inverter gain.

[image]
[image]

I need to plot the maximum gain points (the negative peaks on the gain curves) as a curve with respect to vdd. I have thought of using the `.MEASURE` command to do this.

```
.measure dc g deriv v(out)
.measure dc g_max min g
```

but this gives me an error

```
No. of Data Rows : 1255
        measure 'g'  failed
Error: measure  g  :
        function '' currently not supported
 .measure dc g deriv v(out) failed!
```

I couldn't find any such example in the ngspice pdf manual or their git repository for ngspice simulation examples. Some guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't an EE question but rather a question on how to manipulate graph data in a simulation tool.

Answer (score 1):

Using `deriv` means differentiating across all the length of the trace, so your command `.meas g deriv v(out)` doesn't make sense, since the return value would be a vector of points. The [manual](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice-manual.pdf) describes the usage of `deriv` as a keyword to help evaluating the derivative at one point, either for the respective trace, or through the condition reached with another.

Since this method doesn't seem to allow `min`, `max`, & co, I would recommend you perform the same `.dc` analysis, but in `.tran`:

1. Set up your input as a ramp, e.g. `PWL(0 0 1 2.5)`.
2. Assign `{x}` (or some other value) to your supply.
3. Step through the values of the supply with `.step param x 0.5 2.5 0.5`.

It's enough to plot `V(out)`, only, which will show the correct response, but plotting against `V(in)` would mimic the `.dc` analysis. The advantage of this method is that, if you add a circuit that can perform the derivative of the output, you can use `.meas` to find the `min`/`max`/etc. The circuit is the group formed by `G1` and `L1`, as described [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/532847/95619). Its placement is similar, too: simply connect the noninverting input of `G1` to `V(out)`, and use the voltage across `L1` for the derivative. I'd siggest a timestep 1000x smaller than the total simulation time (e.g. `1 ms` for `1 s`), or less, for sufficient accuracy (to avoid spurious spikes).

With that, if `V(d)` is the derivative, then simply use:

```
.meas d min v(d) from 10m
```

The `from 10m` ensures there are no random spikes in the beginning due to the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

```
* cmos g (gain) vs vdd

*.include tsmc180.txt
.model cmosp pmos
.model cmosn nmos

vdd source_p 0 0v
vin gate_common 0 0v

m_p out gate_common source_p source_p cmosp w=2u l=0.18u
m_n out gate_common 0 0 cmosn w=2u l=0.18u

.dc vin 0 2.5 0.01 vdd 0.5 2.5 0.5
.control
run
let derivout = deriv(v(out))
plot v(out) vs v(gate_common) 
plot derivout vs v(gate_common)
meas dc maxgain min derivout
.endc
.end
```